# How to transform data in character form into a sensible form?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a data output from a device in a form of a string. I need to transform it into such a form that I can work with it, such as plot columns with respect to one another and such. After a apply `Characters` to it it takes the form:

```
   lst={" ", " ", " ", "1", "6", ".", "4", "1", "0", "7", " ", " ", " ", " \
", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "4", ".", "4", "3", "1", "5", \
"e", "-", "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "5", ".", "4", \
"0", "0", "7", "e", "+", "0", "2", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", \
".", "9", "8", "3", "8", "e", "-", "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", \
" ", " ", "2", ".", "4", "1", "7", "7", "e", "+", "0", "2", " ", " ", \
" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "7", ".", "4", "8", "4", "5", "e", "+", "0", \
"0", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "9", ".", "1", "2", "1", "5", \
"e", "+", "0", "3", "\\n", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", "8", \
".", "6", "8", "2", "5", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", \
" ", " ", "1", ".", "2", "2", "0", "1", "e", "+", "0", "0", " ", " ", \
" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", ".", "3", "7", "1", "8", "e", "+", "0", \
"3", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "3", ".", "3", "6", "3", "5", "e", \
"-", "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "3", ".", "6", "0", \
"0", "7", "e", "+", "0", "2", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", \
".", "4", "4", "5", "1", "e", "+", "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", \
" ", " ", "1", ".", "5", "4", "7", "0", "e", "+", "0", "4", "\\n", " \
", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}
```

This is a small part of the data.
 `StringJoin`yields 7 columns, which is how the data is organized

[image]

So, any idea of how to transform it into a normal list?

**Later edit**: to address the question of  bbgodfrey: this is a part of the original output. I add it as an image:

[image]

After I transformed in into characters and cut away first 1360 ones containing the useless billhead, and then combine them back to the string we see 7 columns with numbers that I already posted above.

Comment: As a rough start, try something like `SemanticImportString[StringJoin@StringDelete[lst, "\\n"]]`. This will give you a `Dataset` from which you could get your data, and possibly `Partition` the result into a usable table.

Comment: You mean you want to convert the whole lot into the real-valued list `{16.4107, 4.4315e-01, …}`?

Comment: What does the original output look like?  If one giant string, can you post a part of it?

Comment: @ Patrick Stevens Yes.

Comment: Looks like the kind of job that fits like a glove to `Awk`, `Perl` or similars

Comment: @ MarcoB  This works. Why do not you formulate this as a regular answer?

Comment: @belisarius I unfortunately do not knwo even these words.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch If you're going to work a lot with semi-formatted text files you should try them. `Awk` is easier, `Perl` is more modern and powerful. Google them :)

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of `ReadList["filename", Number, WordSeparators -> {" "}, RecordLists -> True, RecordSeparators -> {"\n"}]` on the file "filename" whose content is `StringJoin[lst]`? ReadList can manage multiple trailing spaces and Fortran-like E notation.

Comment: I think the wrong question is being asked: it should be "how to get `Import[]` to sensibly deal with my data file?"

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica has a very rich set of methods to deal with strings.

```
lst = {" ", " ", " ", "1", "6", ".", "4", "1", "0", "7", " ", " ", 
  " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "4", ".", "4", "3", 
  "1", "5", "e", "-", "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
  "5", ".", "4", "0", "0", "7", "e", "+", "0", "2", " ", " ", " ", 
  " ", " ", " ", "1", ".", "9", "8", "3", "8", "e", "-", "0", "1", 
  " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "2", ".", "4", "1", "7", "7", 
  "e", "+", "0", "2", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "7", ".", 
  "4", "8", "4", "5", "e", "+", "0", "0", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
  " ", " ", "9", ".", "1", "2", "1", "5", "e", "+", "0", "3", "\\n", 
  " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", "8", ".", "6", "8", "2", "5", 
  " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", ".", 
  "2", "2", "0", "1", "e", "+", "0", "0", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
  " ", " ", "1", ".", "3", "7", "1", "8", "e", "+", "0", "3", " ", 
  " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "3", ".", "3", "6", "3", "5", "e", "-", 
  "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "3", ".", "6", "0", 
  "0", "7", "e", "+", "0", "2", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
  "1", ".", "4", "4", "5", "1", "e", "+", "0", "1", " ", " ", " ", 
  " ", " ", " ", " ", "1", ".", "5", "4", "7", "0", "e", "+", "0", 
  "4", "\\n", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}
```

For this answer it will be easier if the string is not broken into characters.

```
text = StringJoin[lst];
```

**Step 1**

Replace the letter "e" with the string "*10^".

```
text1 = StringReplace[text, "e" -> "*10^"]
```

**Step 2**

Break the complete string into a list of lines.

```
lines = StringSplit[text1, "\\n"]
```

For your actual data you would remove the first few lines until you get down to the column of numbers.

**Step 3**

This is the workhorse portion.

We will take the contiguous characters between the spaces and convert them to a number.

```
data = Map[
  StringCases[#, 
    WordBoundary ~~ x : Characters["01234567890-+.*^"] .. ~~ 
      WordBoundary :> ToExpression[x]] &,
  lines
  ]
```

The output is

```
{{16.4107, 0.44315, 540.07, 0.19838, 241.77, 7.4845, 
  9121.5}, {18.6825, 1.2201, 1371.8, 0.33635, 360.07, 14.451, 
  15470.}, {}}
```

**Step 4**

Observe that there is an empty list. The last step is to remove all empty lists.

```
data = DeleteCases[data, {}]
```

yielding the final result

```
{{16.4107, 0.44315, 540.07, 0.19838, 241.77, 7.4845, 
  9121.5}, {18.6825, 1.2201, 1371.8, 0.33635, 360.07, 14.451, 15470.}}
```

Comment: Jack, this looks very promising, but by application to my txt file I get unexpected results on the step 3.  The warning: ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before "*10^". and instead of the removing the whole "cap" each word is replaced by $Failed. Besides, the figures are not splitted into sublists, as expected. The most simple would be to show you the initial txt file, but I do not know, how to do it.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I looked at the text from your answer. For that text in **Step 2** I had to use: lines = StringSplit[text1, EndOfLine]. The rest of it, **Step 3** included worked fine. Make sure if you go to your most raw text you removed the lines that precede the column of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now, how to solve the question partially based on the @ MarcoB advice. Observing that the billhead ends up with "cc/g\n" let us first delete the billhead assuming that `text` is the freshly imported string:

```
text1 = StringDelete[text, __ ~~ "cc/g\n"]
```

This yields the following

```
     16.4540           4.0763e-02       4.9548e+01      1.9462e-02       \
2.3656e+01       7.3634e-01       8.9503e+02
      18.7036           1.1419e-01       1.2807e+02      3.0536e-02   \
    3.2653e+01       1.3133e+00       1.4043e+03
      21.3054           2.0390e-01       2.1228e+02      3.2050e-02   \
    3.0086e+01       1.5700e+00       1.4738e+03
      24.3856           2.1418e-01       2.2071e+02      3.0579e-03   \
    2.5080e+00       1.7143e-01       1.4060e+02
      26.7185           2.1639e-01       2.2236e+02      1.6974e-03   \
    1.2706e+00       1.0440e-01       7.8151e+01
      28.1997           2.1876e-01       2.2404e+02      1.4286e-03   \
    1.0132e+00       9.2736e-02       6.5771e+01
      29.9055           2.2086e-01       2.2545e+02      1.1975e-03   \
    8.0084e-01       8.2435e-02       5.5130e+01
      31.7795           2.2299e-01       2.2679e+02      1.0700e-03   \
    6.7342e-01       7.8275e-02       4.9261e+01
      33.8090           2.2493e-01       2.2794e+02      9.3685e-04   \
    5.5420e-01       7.2909e-02       4.3130e+01
      36.3742           2.2723e-01       2.2920e+02      7.5219e-04   \
    4.1359e-01       6.2962e-02       3.4619e+01
      38.8557           2.2862e-01       2.2991e+02      7.2847e-04   \
    3.7496e-01       6.5162e-02       3.3541e+01
      41.8657           2.3096e-01       2.3103e+02      5.6815e-04   \
    2.7142e-01       5.4726e-02       2.6143e+01
      45.1997           2.3233e-01       2.3164e+02      5.3931e-04   \
    2.3864e-01       5.6115e-02       2.4830e+01
      49.3039           2.3460e-01       2.3256e+02      4.0052e-04   \
    1.6247e-01       4.5419e-02       1.8424e+01
      53.9869           2.3595e-01       2.3306e+02      3.6589e-04   \
    1.3555e-01       4.5465e-02       1.6843e+01
      60.1244           2.3830e-01       2.3384e+02      2.7388e-04   \
    9.1106e-02       3.7853e-02       1.2591e+01
      67.5290           2.3959e-01       2.3423e+02      2.0645e-04   \
    6.1143e-02       3.2078e-02       9.5004e+00
      75.6420           2.4133e-01       2.3469e+02      1.7462e-04   \
    4.6170e-02       3.0370e-02       8.0299e+00
      87.3612           2.4310e-01       2.3509e+02      1.3141e-04   \
    3.0085e-02       2.6382e-02       6.0398e+00
     102.3268           2.4499e-01       2.3546e+02      1.1469e-04   \
    2.2417e-02       2.6965e-02       5.2704e+00
     130.3970           2.4721e-01       2.3580e+02      5.5938e-05   \
    8.5796e-03       1.6665e-02       2.5560e+00
     166.7821           2.4845e-01       2.3595e+02      3.7325e-05   \
    4.4759e-03       1.4287e-02       1.7132e+00
     248.5847           2.5013e-01       2.3608e+02      1.2880e-05   \
    1.0363e-03       7.2000e-03       5.7928e-01
     419.7893           2.5065e-01       2.3611e+02      2.4805e-06   \
    1.1818e-04       2.3458e-03       1.1176e-01
```

Now the idea of MarcoB can be applied:

```
SemanticImportString[text1] // Normal
```

returning this:

```
    {{16.454, 0.040763, 49.548, 0.019462, 23.656, 0.73634, 
  895.03}, {18.7036, 0.11419, 128.07, 0.030536, 32.653, 1.3133, 
  1404.3}, {21.3054, 0.2039, 212.28, 0.03205, 30.086, 1.57, 
  1473.8}, {24.3856, 0.21418, 220.71, 0.0030579, 2.508, 0.17143, 
  140.6}, {26.7185, 0.21639, 222.36, 0.0016974, 1.2706, 0.1044, 
  78.151}, {28.1997, 0.21876, 224.04, 0.0014286, 1.0132, 0.092736, 
  65.771}, {29.9055, 0.22086, 225.45, 0.0011975, 0.80084, 0.082435, 
  55.13}, {31.7795, 0.22299, 226.79, 0.00107, 0.67342, 0.078275, 
  49.261}, {33.809, 0.22493, 227.94, 0.00093685, 0.5542, 0.072909, 
  43.13}, {36.3742, 0.22723, 229.2, 0.00075219, 0.41359, 0.062962, 
  34.619}, {38.8557, 0.22862, 229.91, 0.00072847, 0.37496, 0.065162, 
  33.541}, {41.8657, 0.23096, 231.03, 0.00056815, 0.27142, 0.054726, 
  26.143}, {45.1997, 0.23233, 231.64, 0.00053931, 0.23864, 0.056115, 
  24.83}, {49.3039, 0.2346, 232.56, 0.00040052, 0.16247, 0.045419, 
  18.424}, {53.9869, 0.23595, 233.06, 0.00036589, 0.13555, 0.045465, 
  16.843}, {60.1244, 0.2383, 233.84, 0.00027388, 0.091106, 0.037853, 
  12.591}, {67.529, 0.23959, 234.23, 0.00020645, 0.061143, 0.032078, 
  9.5004}, {75.642, 0.24133, 234.69, 0.00017462, 0.04617, 0.03037, 
  8.0299}, {87.3612, 0.2431, 235.09, 0.00013141, 0.030085, 0.026382, 
  6.0398}, {102.327, 0.24499, 235.46, 0.00011469, 0.022417, 0.026965, 
  5.2704}, {130.397, 0.24721, 235.8, 0.000055938, 0.0085796, 0.016665,
   2.556}, {166.782, 0.24845, 235.95, 0.000037325, 0.0044759, 
  0.014287, 1.7132}, {248.585, 0.25013, 236.08, 0.00001288, 0.0010363,
   0.0072, 0.57928}, {419.789, 0.25065, 236.11, 2.4805*10^-6, 
  0.00011818, 0.0023458, 0.11176}}
```

I thank you for the discussion.